# Google Sheet formula for week number correspondence check (5-week month)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a **Google Sheet** table:
[image]

*SourceSheet Google Sheet (sample data) is available on*: [SourceSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wT4KoLxAIuUvlmKtq0O9ye9LpW0LhCGSEg0xMSR48q8/edit?usp=drive_link)

---

Im trying to create formula **in another sheet** that checks each row (in above SourceSheet): **D10, D11, D12, D13** and so on.. These cells contains current date (day). For example 3 and 8 of January.

- Check if the cell **D** is not empty. If not proceed.
- Check of number in that cell (D10, D11, D12, ...)[date] corresponds to checked column number: **I, J, K, L, M.** So **I** is 1st column, **J** 2nd column, **K** 3rd, **L** 4th, **M** 5th. These columns represent one of the 5 weeks in current month if month divided on 5 (not 4 weeks).
- If day (D10, D11, D12 or another) correspond correctly to week number then check next row. For example, 3 (**D10**)is in 1-st week so it correctly in 1st column **I10**
- If day (D10, D11 or anohter) does not correspond to week number (column number). For example D10 is 3, and 2nd column checked by **1** in **J10**. It's error and formula returns **1**.
- If any of the columns (**I:M**) contain some another value instead of **1** formula returns 1.

If any of the rows does (day) not correspond to column number (week) then formula returns 1 and exits. Of no errors formula returns "".

---

Assumed that each month is divided on 5 weeks. Not 4 weeks. For example January divided in 5 weeks:
[image]

Week 1 is from 1 to 7. Week 2 is from 8 to 14. Week 3 is from 15 to 21. Week 4 is from 22 to 28. Week 5 is from 21 to 31.

---

Code:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wT4KoLxAIuUvlmKtq0O9ye9LpW0LhCGSEg0xMSR48q8/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!D10:D200"))), INT(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wT4KoLxAIuUvlmKtq0O9ye9LpW0LhCGSEg0xMSR48q8/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!D10:D200")/7)+1<>MATCH(1, IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wT4KoLxAIuUvlmKtq0O9ye9LpW0LhCGSEg0xMSR48q8/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!I10:M10"), 0)), 1, ""))<>"", 1, ""), "")
```

---

Does not work. Update: **Desired output:** If one mistake found (first occured mistake) then whole formula returns only **1** and this is printed in my cell as is (not array of 1's). If all rows does not have mistakes within some range then only "" returned by formula once and it printed in cell as is.

Comment: To confirm, do you want your output to be an array of 1's or blanks (" ") corresponding to each of the dates from the source sheet? If possible, please add your expected output format on your sample sheet.

Comment: If one mistake found (first occured mistake) then whole formula returns only 1 and this is printed in my cell as is (not array of 1's). If all rows does not have mistakes within some range then only "" returned by formula once and it printed in cell as is.

Comment: A few questions: 1) You are ok with manually inputting the target range? That is, what the actual format of your data in application? Are they arranged block-by-block in the same sheet, and thus requiring automatic detection of end row per block? Are they arranged sheet-by-sheet, which means you can use unspecified end row as data range?

Comment: 2) Separately, the correct "Visits" for empty "Date" is empty for all 5 weeks? 3) Where does the sheet indicate month/year? (This one is optional since an answer can simply specify the starting weekday of the 1st day of the month and you can incorporate the rest yourself.) 4) Similarly to the question of whether a week starts on Monday or another day

Comment: Lastly, please make example sheets editable so that formulas can be directly passed to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` in conjunction with `offset` as follows

```js
=reduce("",Sheet1!$D$10:$D$20,lambda(a,c,
         if(a="",
            if(c="",
               if(sum(offset(c,0,column(Sheet1!$I:$I)-column(c),1,5))>0,
                  1,
                  ""),
               if(and(sum(offset(c,0,column(Sheet1!$I:$I)-column(c),1,5))=1,
                      offset(c,0,column(Sheet1!I:I)-column(c)+quotient(c-B1+1,7))=1),
                  "",
                  1)),
            a)))
```

where B1 is the weekday number of 1st day of the month.

For example,

- if your sheet is intended for January, 2024 and your starting weekday is Monday, then B1 should be 1, as in your original example.
- If starting weekday had been Sunday, then B1 should be 2.
- If month was February, 2024 and starting weekday is still Monday, then B1 should be 4

When you import the data from an external sheet, be sure to import first such as with `importrange` and then apply the formula in your output sheet.

[image]

Comment: So my output sheet have 50 rows where I need to check 50 such source sheets. It is required to first importRange() data in output sheet and only then use Reduce()? So it is not possible to do it without copying data from external sheet to output sheet?

Comment: @ErbaAitbayev: The thing is, there is no advantage in using `importrange` inline. If anything, you should worry whether there are unecessary repeated calls to external resource if you make multiple inline calls of `importrange`. In order to use `offset`, you need to have explicit ranges. So I am not sure if it can work with `importrange` natively -- though possible. Do try to use `let` in that case. If it turns out you cannot, but you still strongly prefer to use `importrange` inline, you will need to add a layer of `map` usage and the formula won't be as simple

Comment: @ErbaAitbayev: As for 50 rows for a single sheet, you can try adapting the formula for unspecified end row. For importing 50 sheets, how are you getting the file id for `importrange` anyway? If you have the id in the ready, yes, I suggest you import all of them and use `reduce` + `vstack` to lay them out in the same sheet, block by block. So instead of unspecified end row, you may use the combination of `scan` and detection of end row by block to print out all the checked results block by block.