# Google Sheet formula for week day number mapping check [or Google Apps Script]

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have a **Google Sheet** table:
[image]

*SourceSheet Google Sheet (sample data) is available on*: [SourceSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VW5d5Hx7BHu9SqXEKjHIti4a6758naDRBahhBDekhFI/edit?usp=drive_link)

---

Im trying to create formula **in another sheet** that checks each row (in above SourceSheet): **D10, D11, D12, D13** and so on.. These cells contains current date (day). For example 3 and 8 of January.

- Check if the cell **D** is not empty. If not proceed.
- Check of number in that cell (D10, D11, D12, ...)[date] corresponds to checked column number: **I, J, K, L, M.** So **I** is 1st column, **J** 2nd column, **K** 3rd, **L** 4th, **M** 5th. These columns represent one of the 5 weeks in current month if month divided on 5 (not 4 weeks).
- If day (D10, D11, D12 or another) correspond correctly to week number then check next row. For example, 3 (**D10**)is in 1-st week so it correctly in 1st column **I10**
- If day (D10, D11 or anohter) does not correspond to week number (column number). For example D10 is 3, and 2nd column checked by **1** in **J10**. It's error and formula returns **1**.
- If any of the columns (**I:M**) contain some another value instead of **1** formula returns 1.

If any of the rows does (day) not correspond to column number (week) then formula returns 1 and exits. Of no errors formula returns "".

---

Assumed that each month is divided on 5 weeks. Not 4 weeks. For example January divided in 5 weeks:
[image]

Week 1 is from 1 to 7. Week 2 is from 8 to 14. Week 3 is from 15 to 21. Week 4 is from 22 to 28. Week 5 is from 21 to 31.

---

Code:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VW5d5Hx7BHu9SqXEKjHIti4a6758naDRBahhBDekhFI/edit?usp=drive_link", "Sheet1!D10:D200"))), INT(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VW5d5Hx7BHu9SqXEKjHIti4a6758naDRBahhBDekhFI/edit?usp=drive_link", "Sheet1!D10:D200")/7)+1<>MATCH(1, IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VW5d5Hx7BHu9SqXEKjHIti4a6758naDRBahhBDekhFI/edit?usp=drive_link", "Sheet1!I10:M10"), 0)), 1, ""))<>"", 1, ""), "")
```

---

Does not work. Update: **Desired output:** If one mistake found (first occured mistake) then whole formula returns only **1** and this is printed in my cell as is (not array of 1's). If all rows does not have mistakes within some range then only "" returned by formula once and it printed in cell as is.

---

Also tried to use this Reduce formula:

```
=reduce("",Sheet1!$D$10:$D$20,lambda(a,c,
         if(a="",
            if(c="",
               if(sum(offset(c,0,column(Sheet1!$I:$I)-column(c),1,5))>0,
                  1,
                  ""),
               if(and(sum(offset(c,0,column(Sheet1!$I:$I)-column(c),1,5))=1,
                      offset(c,0,column(Sheet1!I:I)-column(c)+quotient(c-B1+1,7))=1),
                  "",
                  1)),
            a)))
```

Sometimes that work. Sometimes that does not.

Comment: I have noticed that this question is similar to your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77870468/google-sheet-formula-for-week-number-correspondence-check-5-week-month) with an accepted answer. Can you elaborate more on `Sometimes that work. Sometimes that does not.`?

Comment: For some tables logic of the code with reduce formula returned "1" corretly. For now I chech it with another similar table of values and it does not return "" when there is no mistake. So there is a mistake in logic of the code.